# Migration to AngularJS 1.2 breaks sortable-wrapper directive

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, angularjs, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a sortable-wrapper directive that allow moving an item inside a list and from a list to another.

With an array container:

```
$scope.container = [
  [{id: '1.1'}, {id: '1.2'}, {id: '1.3'}],
  [{id: '2.1'}, {id: '2.2'}, {id: '2.3'}]
]
```

I use the directive like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="array in container">
  <ul sortable>
    <li ng-repeat="item in array">{{ item.id }}</li>
  </ul> 
</div>
```

When an item is dropped into a list, I have to update items backend side and insert the moved item that is returned by the backend at the right array/index:

```
$scope.move = function (from, fromIndex, to, toIndex) {
  $http.post(url, data).success(function(movedItem) {
    from.splice(fromIndex, 1)[0];
    to.splice(toIndex, 0, movedItem);
  });
}
```

This directive was working well until the version 1.2.0-rc.2, since 1.2.0-rc.3 I get this error when moving an item :

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'insertBefore' of null
    at http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.1/angular.js:3857:22
    at forEach (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.1/angular.js:303:18)
    at Object.enter (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.1/angular.js:3856:9)
    at http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.1/angular.js:18828:26
    at publicLinkFn (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.1/angular.js:5443:29)
    at boundTranscludeFn (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.1/angular.js:5555:21)
    at controllersBoundTransclude (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.1/angular.js:6145:18)
    at ngRepeatAction (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.1/angular.js:18826:15)
    at Object.$watchCollectionAction [as fn] (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.1/angular.js:11347:11)
    at Scope.$digest (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.1/angular.js:11443:27)
```

Here is a plunker that reproduce the error: http://plnkr.co/edit/bAD8z2KdW34a7hkhdyiu?p=preview

Any thought ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I change my implementation to use the angular-ui ui-sortable module. [The angular 1.2 branch](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable/tree/angular1.2) takes into account the changes of 1.2 version of the ng-repeat directive. See the [pull request](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable/pull/56).

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in array track by item.id">{{ item.id }}</li>
```

Why?

I think you are creating items anew (`getNewItemFromBackend(item)`) once their position is changed. Because `ngRepeat` is tracking them by object equality, once an object leaves the list, Angular cannot find it to insert the DOM element. I am not 100% satisfied with this explanation, but it is roughly what is going on.

Comment: With this solution, it does not break anymore when moving an item inside a list, but still breaks when moving an item between lists: http://plnkr.co/edit/fXd2poFJjIPGccgOtk9m?p=preview

Comment: This is caused because both jQueryUI and Angular ngRepeat are changing the DOM, without coordination. I do not know a way to remedy this.